# boot delay on POST on Intel DG43GT board

Tags: boot, motherboard, bios, post

My computer stays at POST for about 20 seconds. Normally this should be 2-3 seconds.

Note I am talking about BIOS POST state. **NOT** Operating system booting state. After this 20 seconds Grub boot menu initializes and it appears after 2-3 seconds. Then I select my OS and it starts booting. So 30-40 seconds after I press the power button on my casing I see the KDM login screen.

On the BIOS POST these are the codes where it gets stuck.

```
BA
92
EB
92
```

It stays most time on *BA* state.

Could you tell me what is the problem? And how do I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The BA code on this motherboard indicates that the POST sequence is detecting the presence of removable media (USB hard drives, CDs inside CD drives, etc). You may want to remove any USB peripherals you have connected to the computer and see if this hastens the POST sequence.

([Source](http://downloadmirror.intel.com/17807/eng/DG43GT_TechProdSpec.pdf), Page 79)

Comment: I have a external powered USB hub where I always connected my external portable hard-disk. After remove this hdd and a usb stick POST time reduces from 30 to 5 seconds!